# How can I get the parameter names of a function stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, reflection

See this code:

```
var method  = function(service,worker){
   //....
}

function getArguments(method){

  //what I want is: 
  //print " the arguments of the method is 'service','worker'"
}

getArguments(method);
```

How can I get the names of the parameters from the variable?

I know `method.arguments` will not work when the method is not called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `toString` on the function, then use a regular expression to extract the argument list from the function definition. Here's a simple example:

```
function getArguments(method){
    // strip off comments
    var methodStr = method.toString().replace(/\/\*.*?\*\/|\/\/.*?\n/g, '');
    var argStr = methodStr.match(/\(([^)]*)\)/);
    alert(argStr[1].split(/\s*,\s*/g));
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/BY5N9/6/)

Comment: If you look closely at the comment in the example code in the question, it looks like he/she actually wants an array of parameter names.

Comment: Is this guaranteed behaviour, or is it specific to the implementation of ES?

Comment: @Sam `argStr[1].match(/[$\w]+/g)` will produce an array of parameter names (although admittedly it won't handle Unicode identifiers like `ಠ_ಠ`). I believe the precise formatting of the string that's returned by `mothod.toString()` may vary, but the fact that it returns the function definition is part of the ECMAScript standard.

Comment: Oops; I didn't see that you were doing two `match`es.

Comment: Doesn't work with space between args http://jsfiddle.net/BY5N9/2/ can it be made universal?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Thanks. Already updated and now accepts Unicode identifiers.

Comment: It also doesn't work with something like this: `function (arg1, /*)*/ arg2){}`. I guess ultimately you need to actually *parse* the function definition to get the parameter names out.

Comment: @Sam Updated to handle both line and block comments